# Can not use "pathping" command in macOS

Tags: macos, mac

In the Windows I can use the `pathping` command to tail after the network path, but I can not find this command on macOS.

Is it has another name, such as `ipconfig` to `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 8):

In macOS Terminal, you can use `traceroute` for similar functionality.

There's also a nice GUI tool called `Network Utility` that you can use to trace a path of your network traffic (in this example I've traced `www.apple.com`):

[image]

In OS X Mavericks (10.9) and later, `Network Utility` is in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications`.

In OS X Mountain Lion (10.8), Lion (10.7), and Snow Leopard (10.6), Network Utility is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.

Comment: Just a heads up for the OP, tracert does not measure packet loss over time like `pathping` does.

Comment: Network utility has been deprecated in macos bigsur

Answer (score 8):

The comparable command, `mtr`, can be installed with a package manager, such as [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). After installing Homebrew, one can install the software as follows.

```
brew install mtr
```

If desired, one might also make an alias for `pathping`. For example, in BASH...

```
alias pathping='sudo /usr/local/sbin/mtr'
```

The familiar result is illustrated below.

[image: mtr]

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to say that Christopher provides the most accurate answer here.

Traceroute and pathping are 2 different tools that do the same thing in a different ways. By suggesting traceroute you're suggesting **alternative** tool and not **equivalent** tool and thats a big difference. OP is asking for equivalent, not alternative and mtr is the closest equivalent.

As written here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42886/difference-of-tracert-and-pathping

> **PING**, is an application based on the ICMP protocol which is used to send echo packets to a destination and expecting to receive an echo
> response and it calculates the RTT (Round Trip Time) from when the
> packet was sent to when the echo response was received. Generally when
> using PING on a LAN network you can trust that what it is saying is
> accurate unless you have foreknowledge of network devices in the
> transit path that prioritize ICMP over mission critical TCP/UDP
> Traffic. This however is very common in networks that utilize unified
> communications, meaning voice and data on the same network. This is
> because QoS Policies are put in place to ensure voice traffic and
> other mission critical traffic is prioritized over ICMP thus
> indirectly affecting the RTT time of an ICMP ping test.
>
> **Trace-route** is another method commonly used by technicians and engineers to diagnosis latency in the transit path however any
> engineer that has studied how trace-route works would know that its
> results are nearly always misleading.
>
> Trace-route works in a manner similar to ping however it uses the TTL feature to make each successive hop in the transit path respond
> with an ICMP TTL Expired packet. Thus gives you the ability to
> determine which network devices the ICMP packet is traversing.
>
> When you dig deeper into the operation of traceroute you will see that traceroute utilizes 3 probe packets for each successive hop by
> default unless you specify other wise. Each probe packet indirectly
> measures the latency between the source and the device where the TTL
> is declared expired. This latency calculation is a by product of its
> true intended purpose. Keep in mind even if you send probes to a
> device that is five hops away, random latency spikes in any four
> devices prior to the fifth hop can result in the fifth hop looking
> like it has high latency.
>
> **Pathping** works first by doing a traceroute to the destination then it uses ICMP to ping each hop in the transit path 100 times. This is
> used to verify latency between the source and destination via icmp
> echo per each hop. But remember what I said earlier, you cannot rely
> ICMP when public devices are involved. So you can run into cases where
> you see ICMP pings destined to one hop in the transit drop 40% of the
> traffic whereas the next hop has 100% success rate. This is due to
> CoPP.
>
> Pathping in general is a much better tool to diagnosis latency from a specific source to destination with a relative degree of
> accuracy. Note that I said Relative, this is because latency is ALWAYS
> relative to your location on the network.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Terminal too.

```
traceroute <ip address>
```

Also you  could do a ping too.

```
ping <ip address>
```

Network Utility is nice in that it wraps all the utilities in one tool.

I'd guess that you could write a shell script which wraps both together which it sounds like pingpath does.

Comment: Honestly traceroute is not same pathping. Mac has already have traceroute and we can track the ping but less informant way.